# Swift sortinplace binary operator > cannot be applied to two nsnumber operands

Tags: ios, swift

I have been toying around learning core data in swift. I have an array populated with Person core data objects with various attributes. the following is the attribute I am having trouble with:

```
@NSManaged var id: Int
```

The id attribute is set to Int32 in my managed object model. I found using this on a 64-bit architecture is throwing an error: Property setId: is a 64 bit scalar type on class 'Person' that does not match its entity's property's 32 bit scalart type..... if I understand right my device is using 64 bit Int's instead of 32-bit which is why I should be using @NSManaged var id:NSNumber? instead. I fixed this in my managed object subclass of person, but in the array I am populating with Person objects I wanted to sort it based on the id attribute using:

```
people.sortInPlace({$0.id > $1.id})
```

After changing the id attribute in my managed object subclass to NSNumber i get the error that I cannot use the > binary operator on two NSNumber operands. How would I go about sorting based on the id attribute now?

Comment: Have you tried using `Int32` instead of `NSNumber`?

Comment: Of course you can use scalar properties for integer attributes on all architectures. For an "Integer 32" attribute the property must be defined as `@NSManaged var id: Int32`. – Or (better) let Xcode generate the managed object subclass files!

Comment: Thats what had me confused; I didn't see why I was getting the error with scalar property. I didn't think about changing it to Int32. I just tried that and the sort is working without converting it to NSNumber :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Crap I am a moron, as soon as I posted this I realized what I wanted to do. NSNumber has an intValue function! Just needed to change it to

```
people.sortInPlace{($0.id.intValue > $1.id.intValue)}
```